# Using the raspberry Pi to connect to a websocket provided by a node server with socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, raspberry-pi, raspbian

**Thanks for taking the time to have a look at my question.**

I would like to use many raspberry pi's as part of the solution to a problem. For it, I need instantaneous 2-way communication. I'd much rather use existing websockets provided by a server in the cloud running node.js and socket.io.

I need the Raspberry Pi's to connect to the internet, go to the node.js server where it should get and maintain an active socket connection to the cloud server.

I doubt it's *impossible*, but the serious lack of any information on Raspberry Pi as a client implies that there is perhaps a "better" way...

The raspberry pi will not have a screen, or any input peripherals other than its sensor connections... Meaning no user interaction, no browser etc... which is where I'm hitting the how to actually serve socket.io to the raspberry pi and have it initiate a connection.

**All comments, suggestions and answers are greatly appreciated.**

**Thanks all for your time.**

Grant.

Comment: Why not just use a TCP client/server.

Comment: The node.js server with socket.io on it already exists, and I'd rather reuse this part if I could...

Comment: Well socket.io has a [client](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client) for Node.js.

Comment: Maybe http://eureca.io can help